# Spring boot environment property returns null

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot 2 app. I am trying to access my application properties file properties through spring Environment as well as @Value property, neither of them works.

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

logger.info(env.getProperty("app.environment"));


@Value("${app.environment}")
private String _env;

logger.info(_env);
```

[image]

app.environment=LOCAL

Looks like spring boot is not detecting application.properties file at all.

What am I doing wrong here, Thanks in advance

Comment: can you put a complete example or your class? i would like to see the structure of your complete class

Comment: have you annotated you class with `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Configuration`  or etc ?

Answer (score 2):

If the injected property is null, it most probably means your bean has not been created yet. Spring boot injects values to bean properties only after the bean has been created.

Here's a simple experiment to demonstrate this behavior:

```
@Value("${spring.application.name}")
private String instanceApplicationName;

public UserController(@Value("${spring.application.name}") String appNameInConstructor)  {
    System.out.println("Constructor app name: " + appNameInConstructor);
    System.out.println("Instance application name: " + this.instanceApplicationName);
}
```

Which property would be null? instanceApplicationName or appNameInConstructor?

Yes, it's the *instanceApplicationName* property that's *null* because, the constructor is called first and the instance property has not been initialized yet. The *appNameInConstructor* correctly logs the application name.

So, where you reference the injected properties and how you inject them, both matter.

You can check the entire project here: https://github.com/nkumashi/springboot-webmvc-demo.